# Issue on framing Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

Code:

```
IQueryable<Meet> query = _meetReadService.GetRecords()
                                 .Include(x => x.MeetType)
                                 .Where(x => x.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
```

When I am adding the following line to the above linq query, the error message is thrown as

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

```
x => x.MeetTeamMembers.Where(e => e.MeetType.IsManager)
                      .Select(z => z.User.Name)
                      .FirstOrDefault()
```

My full code:

```
 IQueryable<Meet> query = _meetReadService.GetRecords()
           .Include(x => x.MeetType)
           .Include(x => x.MeetTeamMembers.Where(e => e.MeetType.IsManager)
                                          .Select(z => z.User.Name)
                                          .FirstOrDefault())
           .Where(x => x.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Entity Framework or LINQ-to-SQL?

Comment: Is MeetType mapped to the database or is it just a simple property? ORMs can't work with properties that aren't mapped to the database

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do filtering within a call to `Include`. This means that the `.Where(e => e.MeetType.IsManager)` is the culprit. What you want can only be done *after* the query has executed:

```
IQueryable<Meet> query = _meetReadService.GetRecords()
                                         .Include(x => x.MeetType)
                                         .Include(x => x.MeetTeamMembers)
                                         .Select(z => z.User.Name).FirstOrDefault())
                                         .Where(x => x.EndDateTime <= DateTime.Now);

var queryResults = query.ToList();

foreach (var meet in queryResults) 
{
    meet.MeetTeamMembers = meet.MeetTeamMembers.Where(e => e.MeetType.IsManager);
}
```